# How do I check to see how many bytes are left until EOL in Go?

Tags: string, go, byte

Let's say that I have a file like this:

```
John
Marcus
Tom
```

Each of the strings are inputted by the user and therefore I do not know the size of them.
How would I make a function that would check how many bytes are left until the EOL?

Comment: The question as written doesn't really make sense. You have the file, and you know the bytes of that file, so you know how many bytes there are between newline characters. Can you explain the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @JimB Sorry if the question was confusing. I just gave an example of what the file could look like. All of the names (John, Marcus, Tom) are inputted by the user and can change.

Comment: @HomoMusculus The looks like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  Describe the higher-level problem that you are trying to solve by getting the count of bytes before EOL.  For example, are you trying to read the file line by line?

Comment: There are possibly multiple EOL. Are you trying to get the number of bytes until the next EOL, to get the array of the length of all of the lines, or to get the number of bytes until the last EOL ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you just want to read a plain text file line by line? :D

names.txt:

```
John
Marcus
Tom
```

main.go:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("names.txt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        line := scanner.Text()
        fmt.Println("name:", line)
        fmt.Println("length:", len(line))
    }
}
```

output:

```
name: John
length: 4
name: Marcus
length: 6
name: Tom
length: 3
```

Comment: It is a different approach but it works. Thanks!